# Tastypie - How can authorize only the owner to edit a resource

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I am creating my first API with tastypie and I would like to know how can I set that only owners can edit it's own resources.

Should I?

- create a basic authentication like in [this](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization) example
- check if the request.user is the same of the resource.owner
- check if the request is a PUT

Is this the best way to fo it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you described is an ok way to do it. Alternatively you could manipulate methods involved in updates: `put_detail()` and `obj_update()` but your idea is probably a bit cleaner as after all what you try to do is obviosuly [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization). Therefore the code belongs in the `Authorization` class not in the methods which actually update the objects as those shouldn't even be called when the user is not authorized to update given resource.

You may also want to look at Tastypie Cookbok which now has a "recipe" for [creating "per-user" resoures](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources) which also describes how to list resources belonging to a given user only.